# Android textinputlayout on adding left padding to the layout i get an equal amount of space on the right side and it looks as a margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

On adding paddingleft to textinputlayout an equal number of spacing is applied to right hand side as if a margin is applied.

fragment_add_task.xml with left padding:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        style="@style/RR_12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hiiiii"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/lightGrayColor" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Result screen :
[With padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Kyw.jpg)

But when i remove that leftpadding it comes back to normal.

fragment_add_task.xml with left padding:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        style="@style/RR_12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hiiiii"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/lightGrayColor" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Result screen :
[Without padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WObBB.jpg)

So anyone can help or guide me what is causing this issue.

Update :
My style(TextInputLayout) which is assign to textinputlayout view

```
<style name="TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/darkWhiteColor</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">@dimen/one_dp</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">@dimen/ten_dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">@dimen/ten_dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">@dimen/ten_dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">@dimen/ten_dp</item>
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutHintStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Why are you using android:layout_width="0dp" ? Also post the TextInputLayout and the RR_12 styles

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti becoz parent layout is ConstraintLayout and RR_12 is a style for text font like in this case it is roboto_regular of 12 font size

Comment: <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/ten_dp</item> is a padding that i add